# How much space should / and /home partition have

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

so I followed a blog post about installing Ubuntu alongside Windows and I had to the the "Other" option during the install. The blog said to create `root` partition mounted to `/` and `home` partition mounted to `/home`. It didn't say which partition is used for what though. I allocated 150GB to root and 6GB to home. Was that a mistake? What is stored on / and what is stored on /home?

I'll provide an image of system monitor "File System" so you can see what I'm talking about.

[image: file systems]

Comment: I typically allocate 30GB to / (root). Your data goes into /home and we have no idea how much data you want to save. But if /home less than 30 or 40GB then better to just have it inside / and only have the one partition. lInstaller now creates swap file, so swap partition not required. Those with servers still suggest a swap partition. Note that you have used 8.9GB of / and that will grow with log files & cruft. I typically houseclean older log files and try to find other cruft to delete. But do a new / partition for next LTS version so I only get 2 years of cruft.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It is much more clear now. Do I have to reinstall the OS in order to fix the partitions or can I do it inside of Ubunutu?

Comment: You cannot change mounted partitions. You can use gparted from live installer. If a partition has lots of data a move can take a long time. Never interrupt it or you damage partition and lose data. Or good backups required. If you have not made lots of configuration changes or saved lots of data, you probably can just edit partitions. If drives are in order p5, then p6, you can just shrink p5 & move p6 left. If reversed bit more difficult.

Comment: @oldfred "houseclean older log files" - we have a tool for automating that: `man logrotate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's definitely not the right choice. To summarise what these partitions are:

1. root (/) is the one which operating system uses. For example application binaries and things like that. It's typically 20GB or more depending on the requirement. But leaving a huge space for this partition is generally not advised. I've used 50GB for my machine that's more than enough.
2. swap (swap) it helps operating system manage the memory when RAM is getting used up. Typically it will be double the size of the RAM. (Ex: 2 GB RAM machine requires 4GB swap space.
3. home (/home) is the one where user's data is stored. There is no upper limit for this partition. It all depends on how much data you wanted to store.

Coming back to your scenario

You should have 30GB or so for your root, swap is based on your RAM and you can do the math and finally all remaining space for home.

Hope this helps

Comment: A swap partition is not needed since recent versions of Ubuntu use swapfile instead.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That's what I thought but I wanted to confirm since I'm no expert. Do I have to reinstall the OS or can I do it without reinstalling?

Comment: Thanks @mook765 I was not aware of this.

Comment: @crodev You would need to do it again. Repeat the process based on the documentation you referred and size the partitions like I mentioned above. swap is optional as mentioned by mook765

Comment: Ok good stuff to know. Thank you again!

Comment: You can also boot your installer to run a live session, and resize the partitions with gparted.